# Under the current COVID restrictions, can a permanent resident of Japan go abroad and return?

Tags: japan, covid-19

In sifting through the various government sites I can guess at an answer, but I've not found anywhere that clearly says "Permanent residents are able to re-enter Japan after going abroad."

Does such a source exist?  If not, what sources can be combined to reasonably infer whether or not permanent residents can return?

(Note the question is not asking about COVID prevention related obligations on return to Japan--presentation of a testing certificate, etc.--but simply about re-entry permission for permanent residents specifically.)

Comment: ANA says directly that permanent residents can return: 永住権をお持ちの方は、日本国籍以外でも入国は可能です https://www.ana.co.jp/ja/jp/topics/coronavirus-travel-information/immigration/ However, I'm not yet able to find where it is written so plainly on the MOJ site to which the ANA page links, so I didn't use this source for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself.  The below PDFs dated 2021/11/29 state that re-entry permission is still valid.

https://www.moj.go.jp/isa/content/001347330.pdf

```
次の(1)から(4)のいずれかに該当する場合には，特段の事情があるものと
して上陸を許可します。
...
(1)再入国許可(みなし再入国許可を含む。以下同じ。)をもって再入国する外国
人
```

https://www.moj.go.jp/isa/content/001359621.pdf

```
If any of the following (1) to (4) applies to the foreign national, landing
will be permitted on the premise that there are special exceptional
circumstances.
...
(1) Foreign nationals entering Japan with re-entry permit (including a
special re-entry permit; the same applies hereinafter).
```

Permanent residency carries with it re-entry permission, and so permanent residents are allowed to re-enter Japan even under the current restrictions.